# Property wrapper auto-completion fails in SwiftUI in Xcode 13.2

Tags: xcode, swiftui

When I'm writing a SwiftUI view and I need to add a Property Wrapper (@State, @Binding, etc.), the auto-completion don't work.

Is this a bug, or a misconfiguration on my part?

I'm using Xcode 13.2 (13C90), in a 3.6 GHz Intel Core i9 with a 32GB of RAM

Comment: Yeah it doesn’t work for me either. But it’s only like 10 characters, not too hard to type out

Comment: Consider filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I'm also experiencing trouble with auto-completion in Xcode 13.2 - for example: typing `numberOfRowsInSection` no longer to auto-completes to `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { ... }` inside a UITableViewController.

Comment: @TD540 you might need to put “override” in front

Comment: @aheze if you watch a few seconds here: https://youtu.be/0hMgOfF8tyQ?t=557, Paul's just typing `numberOfRowsIn...` + enter, and it generates the whole overridden tableView func. A whole lot of other autocompletions are missing for me, like String's `init(contentsOf:)` here for example: https://developer.apple.com/forums/content/attachment/55841afd-5707-43cd-bcd1-91700ba8a3c5

Comment: After completely purging Xcode and every folder related to Xcode, I still had this exact problem after reinstalling 13.2 from Apple Dev site. So I ended up completely reinstalling macOS and Xcode and now it's all back to normal. Jeez :)